# ExtJS 6 Change items using reponsive config

Tags: extjs, extjs6

Is it possible to change `items` with `responsiveConfig`?

I've tried to do something like:

```
{
    xtype: 'container',
    layout: {
        type: 'hbox',
        pack: 'center'
    },
    defaults: {
        xtype: 'box'
    },
    plugins: 'responsive',
    // Simple items configuration is for example only
    responsiveConfig: {
        'width <= 768': {
            items: [
                {
                    html: 'Less than 768'
                }
            ]
        },
        'width > 768': {
            items: [
                {
                    html: 'More than 768'
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

but I get the following error when screen size changes:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at constructor.init (:1841/ext/build/ext-all-debug.js?_dc=1502287779074:233268)
    at constructor.invalidate (:1841/ext/build/ext-all-debug.js?_dc=1502287779074:235386)
    at constructor.invalidate (:1841/ext/build/ext-all-debug.js?_dc=1502287779074:235435)
    at constructor.invalidate (:1841/ext/build/ext-all-debug.js?_dc=1502287779074:235435)
    at constructor.invalidate (:1841/ext/build/ext-all-debug.js?_dc=1502287779074:235435)
    at constructor.flushInvalidates (:1841/ext/build/ext-all-debug.js?_dc=1502287779074:235261)
    at constructor.run (:1841/ext/build/ext-all-debug.js?_dc=1502287779074:235764)
    at Function.flushLayouts (:1841/ext/build/ext-all-debug.js?_dc=1502287779074:64540)
    at Function.resumeLayouts (:1841/ext/build/ext-all-debug.js?_dc=1502287779074:64555)
    at Object.Ext.resumeLayouts (:1841/ext/build/ext-all-debug.js?_dc=1502287779074:70319)
```

I've tried to create fiddle to illustrate this issue, but is seems that responsive config doesnt work properly within fiddle.

UPDATE: Thanks to @scebotari66, solved by adding `setItems` method to `Ext.container.Container`:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.container.Container', {
    override: 'Ext.container.Container',

    setItems: function (component)
    {
        if (this.hasOwnProperty('items')) {
            this.removeAll();
            this.add(component);
        }
        // If container is not initialized yet
        else {
            this.items = Ext.isArray(component) ? component : [component];
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice this excerpt from the [responsiveConfig](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.mixin.Responsive.html#cfg-responsiveConfig) documentation:

> For a config to participate as a responsiveConfig it must have a
>   "setter" method.

The containers do not have a `setItems` method. So in order for this to work, you need to create one yourself. It should basically clean all existing items and add the new ones.